# Enable lock key in Monterey on iMac M1 magic keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, imac, monterey

How do I enable the lock key (or keyboard lock button) in Monterey 12.0.1 on iMac M1 (8GB 2021) standard issue magic keyboard (without FingerID, just a lock key)?

I upgraded from Big Sur to Monterey 12.0.1, and then the lock key on magic keyboard went from working (Big Sur) to not working or inactive in Monterey.

I searched the settings but no mention of the lock key/button anywhere. Also, ideally I'd like to be able to set its function to e.g. command centre.